# extracting value from JSON array

Tags: java, json

I want to extract a value from JSON below using JSONObject. The value is inside `data`and in this case is 3:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "count(n)"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      3
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried  `JSONArray jsonMainArr = jsonRes.getJSONArray("data");` and it's displaying `[[3]]`, how to extract that number 3 ?

Comment: `jsonMainArr[0][0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` element holds nested array.

Since you already have this array in

```
JSONArray jsonMainArr = jsonRes.getJSONArray("data");
```

you can get its first (and only) inner array `[3]` with

```
jsonMainArr.getJSONArray(0)
```

Now you need to get its only element. You can do it with `get(0)`, or to get more precise return type `getInt(0)`.

This should work fine for you

```
int value = jsonRes.getJSONArray("data").getJSONArray(0).getInt(0);
```

Comment: @Frugo I'm glad you like it :)